# How to programmatically create Vue Components indirectly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm attempting to add components programatically to a page in my Vue Single file Component which works beautifully if you know what you'd like to do ahead of time. In my case, the components and their layout will be received via JSON and I'm attempting to create them dynamically. Below you can see I'd like to do something like eval but this doesn't work for uninstantiated objects unfortunately. The code below is simplified with hardcoded values to get the point across.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>Static template:</h2>
    <InputTemplate type="text"></InputTemplate>
    <h2>Dynamically inserted:</h2>
    <div ref="container">
      <button @click="onClick">Click to insert</button>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>  

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
//the component I'd like to create
import InputTemplate from './components/InputTemplate.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { InputTemplate },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      //I'd like to do something like this, but eval doesn't work like this
      var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(eval('InputTemplate'))
      var instance = new ComponentClass({
        propsData: {type: 'text' }
      })
      instance.$mount()
      this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I put together a helper function below that replaces eval and works, but feels kinda inelegant for the solution. It also requires a lot of upkeep for each new component added. Is there a better way to do this?

```
returnComponent(componentString){
      if(componentString === 'InputTemplate'){
        return InputTemplate;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried [Async components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components)?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, using Async components would allow me to dynamically import the components as necessary by calling them with something like `myComponent: () => import(myComponent)`?

Comment: I haven't tried myself but this also how I understand it. I think you can replace the `import` function with another function returning a component object inside a Promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Vue has `<component :is="yourComponentType">` which does exactly what I was hoping to accomplish if you throw it into a `v-for` loop. [Documents here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) to retrieve a component via an API.

I've tested with GraphQL via Axios but it should work with any REST service.

The main component looks like that:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div><button @click="clicked = true">Load component</button></div>
    <async-component v-if="clicked" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clicked: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    'async-component': () => axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql', { query: `
      {
        asyncComponentByRowId(rowId: 1) {
          component
          content
        }
      }
    `,
    }).then((response) => {
      const comp = response.data.data.asyncComponentByRowId.content;
      // eval can be harmful
      return eval(`(${comp})`);
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

The retrieved component is in the following format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "asyncComponentByRowId": {
      "component": "my-async-component",
      "content": "{\r\n\ttemplate: '<div>{{ msg }}</div>',\r\n\tdata: function() {\r\n\t\treturn {\r\n\t\t\tmsg: 'Async component works!'\r\n\t\t};\r\n\t}\r\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

The decoded `data.asyncComponentByRowId.content` property is a string representing a JavaScript object:

```
{
  template: '<div>{{ msg }}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      msg: 'Async component works!'
    };
  }
}
```

When the button is pressed, the component is shown after being downloaded from the API asynchronously.

The only problem is that I'm using `eval` to decode the object.

Result:

[image: Async component screenshot]